# Number of stream maps must match number of output streams running ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Trying to cut a fragment from MKV video, but getting an error.

What can be a reason?

```
V:\VIDEO>ffmpeg -ss 00:42:35 -t 00:43:05 -i smenia.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy clientalwaysright.mkv
FFmpeg version SVN-r21566-xuggle-3.4.843, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  built on Jan 31 2010 09:45:05 with gcc 4.2.4 (TDM-1 for MinGW)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local --extra-version=xuggle-3.4.843 --extra-cflags=-I/c/hudson/slave/workspace/xuggle_xu
bel/WindowsXP_i386/build/native/i686-pc-mingw32/captive/usr/local/include --extra-ldflags=-L/c/hudson/slave/workspace/xu
JDK5/label/WindowsXP_i386/build/native/i686-pc-mingw32/captive/usr/local/lib --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-nonfr
libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --enable-libfaac --enable-libopencor
mrwb --extra-cflags=-mno-cygwin --extra-cflags=-fno-common --extra-ldflags=-mno-cygwin --extra-ldflags=--out-implib --en
ign-hack
  libavutil     50. 8. 0 / 50. 8. 0
  libavcodec    52.49. 0 / 52.49. 0
  libavformat   52.48. 0 / 52.48. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libswscale     0. 9. 0 /  0. 9. 0
[matroska @ 0x1f17270]max_analyze_duration reached
[matroska @ 0x1f17270]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 47.95 (66893/1395) -> 23.98 (24000/1001)
Input #0, matroska, from 'smenia.mkv':
  Duration: 01:52:36.41, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 1280x544, PAR 1:1 DAR 40:17, 24.39 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0.1(rus): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16
    Metadata:
      description     : rus MVO
    Stream #0.2(rus): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16
    Metadata:
      description     : rus OVO
    Stream #0.3(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16
    Stream #0.4(rus): Subtitle: 0x0000
    Stream #0.5(eng): Subtitle: 0x0000
File 'clientalwaysright.mkv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Number of stream maps must match number of output streams
```

Comment: Just curious: Did you get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please [download a recent version of FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html). The one you're using is more than three years old, and I'm fairly sure it should just work with a recent build – quite a few things have been changed since then.

You can  then simply do:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:42:35 -i smenia.mkv -map 0 -c copy -t 00:43:05 clientalwaysright.mkv
```

It's enough to specify `-map 0` to tell FFmpeg to map all streams from the input, including the subtitles. The `-c copy` option will tell it to do a bitstream copy for video, audio and subtitle streams. No need to explicitly specify the `copy` codec for each stream anymore.

If you only want to map specific audio and subtitle channels (e.g., first audio and first subtitle stream), doing this should work fine:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:42:35 -i smenia.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:s:0 -c copy -t 00:43:05 clientalwaysright.mkv
```

I moved the `-t` option after the input, as it's not an input option and should go between `-i` and your output file name. If you want your cut to be more accurate, consider moving `-ss` after `-i`. Refer to [the documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) for more.